# Applying user-entered data in one view to a second view

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I'm trying to write an iphone OS app that includes a logbook feature. The problem that I'm having is that I want each new logbook to have its own categories that are user-defined, for example a chemical receipt log would have chemical name, vendor, receipt date, expiration date and comments.

The way that I'm trying to go about this is by calling an editCategory view controller when a new logbook is created that contains a number of UITextields where the user can enter the categories. I want to take those strings and apply them to a newLogEntry view controller, so that when the user creates a new log entry, they are presented with each category followed by a UITextfield so they can enter the relevant data.

The trick is, I have no idea how to grab the category data from editCategory and apply it to newLogEntry. I'm currently using Core Data, as that seems to be the easiest way to go about this, but I'm not married to it if it interferes with a good solution. Also, I'm still more comfortable with genetic code than objective-C code, so please bear with my ignorance.

Comment: I guess I just needed to ask the question. Do I just need to add a 'category' attribute to my Logbook entity? I think I'll go try that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the App Delegate? You could keep those values in the App Delegate, and call on them in the ViewDidLoad method of your newLogEntry view controller.

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of that. I'm thinking that this would require a method that writes the values from editCategory to an NSMutableString? Would that work with multiple logs? (To use in my labs, there would be 5-17 logbooks.)